# Jquery and adding row to table

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery code.

```
var destTable = $("#numbers");
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnAdd").click(function() {
   //Take the text, and also the ddl value and insert as table row.
   var newRow = $("<tr><td>hi</td></tr>");
   $("#numbers").append(newRow);
  });
});
```

What I would really like is to store a reference to an element once and then use it from there on it.

The code above add's a row to my table as expected but if I use. `$(destTable).append(newRow)` or `destTable.append(newRow)` nothing happens could anyone shed any light on this for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Keep the reference inside document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var destTable = $("#numbers");
  $("#btnAdd").click(function() {
   //Take the text, and also the ddl value and insert as table row.
   var newRow = $("<tr><td>hi</td></tr>");
   $("#numbers").append(newRow);
  });
});
```

The point of document.ready is to wait for the DOM to be ready; if you try doing `$('#numbers');` outside of it (and the code does not appear after the element in the document) the DOM will not have yet created this element so you won't have a proper reference to it.

Once you do this, you should be able to do:

```
destTable.append(newRow);
```

Inside the `click` function. As a last note, however, it is a common and accepted practice to preface variables that represent jQuery sets with a `$`. So this is best:

```
var $destTable = $("#numbers");
```

Comment: Makes sense when I thought about it cheers for that worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Your can use appendTo like this :

```
$("<tr><td>Hello</td><tr>").appendTo("#MyTable > tbody")
```

Comment: Should that not be <tr><td>Hello</td></tr> ?

Comment: @MadMaardigan YES! :)