# How to append rows/cells to a table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Adding rows to a table with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067758/adding-rows-to-a-table-with-jquery)
>   [Jquery and adding row to table.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067828/jquery-and-adding-row-to-table)

I currently have a table that has one row and with this table row, I have five cells where a user can place in required information.

What I would like to achieve is a means of having an "Add Row" button using jQuery, by where the user can create on the fly, additional rows/cells within this table if required by pressing the "Add Row" button.

Basically would like to keep appending rows within this table and then go through each of these rows and store the data into a database table.

Answer (score 2):

See my answer here: [Adding rows to a table with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067758/adding-rows-to-a-table-with-jquery/6067783#6067783)

Comment: Thanks Neal - looks good to me but on this, let's say I also wanted to introduce the ability to remove a row just added from the bottom or even the second record if there were 5 records in total?

Comment: @tonsils. add a mechanism to know when you create a row, add it an array, and then you can control from there.